# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer Change to AspectFill

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, gravity, bounds

I would like my `Session` to be shown in an aspectFill way inside my `AVCamPreviewLayer`. While the code below does just that, it fills the full screen not just the view the preview layer is hooked up to on the storyboard. So I would like to in some way fill the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to the bounds of my `previewView` not the full screen when changing the `gravity`.

```
  [(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
```

I have also tried

```
- (void)setSession:(AVCaptureSession *)session
{
    ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).bounds = ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).bounds;
    [(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[self layer] setSession:session];
}
```

** Note this does come from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)